# What is the best way to pass a model to an include file?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-include

I'm learning AngularJs and I got to a small brick wall...

when I want to split items into tabs, my template is exactly the same for all the tabs, the only small change if the model used in the `ng-repeat`, as an example:

```
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tier6">
        <div ng-include="'partials/vehicles-6-details.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tier8">
        <div ng-include="'partials/vehicles-8-details.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tier10">
        <div ng-include="'partials/vehicles-10-details.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way I have to create 3 exact files, where the template is:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline list-tier">
    <li ng-repeat="tank in tankInfoLevel6" data-sortby="{{playersByTankId[tank].length}}">
        <span class="badge">{{playersByTankId[tank].length}}</span>
        <img ng-src="{{tankInfo[tank].image}}" alt="" class="tank-img"
             pop-over title="Tank fans" fans="tanksFans[tank]" />
        <br><b>{{tankInfo[tank].name_i18n}}</b>
        <br>({{tankInfo[tank].type_i18n}})
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the only change is `tankInfoLevel6` by `tankInfoLevel8` and `tankInfoLevel10` respectively.

How can I use a simple file?

I've tried:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/vehicles-details.html'" 
     ng-init="tierTanks = tankInfoLevel6"></div>
```

and also with `onLoad` and `onInclude` without any good results.

The output is showing the last tab contents in all tabs, so it seems that it loads all but the last call with `tankInfoLevel10` is the one that overrides all the tabs.

Is there a way to make this work neatly?

Answer (score 0):

What about ng-repeat?

```
<div ng-repeat="tankItem in tankItems">
    <div ng-include="'partials/vehicles-details.html'"></div>
</div>
```

In template use tankItem.

Comment: I could make an `array` of all the 3 models I have, but that is not "neat" it's just hacking :)

Comment: Why hacking?... Anyway, you can always make directive for this if u want.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a directive work better here, using an attribute to pass/reference the tankItems list?

Comment: I'm trying to learn it without using a directive, but maybe, in the long way, it's the cleanest and simple way to accomplish such thing...